# Hibernate, Spring Web Service transaction issue

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc, spring-ws, hibernate-annotations

I have two applications. One is OrderService and another is TradeService.
In trade service there is a method 'Buy' which is transactional.

Issue arises when Trade Service calls SubmitOrder method of Order service using Web Service.

Description of Issue:

1. All steps in Buy method are under one transaction.
2. When we call buy method it creates one Order Object.
3. When this method calls Submit Order method using web service, It passes order Id.
4. Submit Order method use this Id to load Order Object from DB.
5. But in Load method It gives Lazy Initialization Exception: Session is closed.
   (Both Applications share same Database)
6. Probable solution to  this is make Submit Order method transactional.
7. It leads to another Deadlock issue.

   - Reason for deadlock,
     A. Buy method Locks Order Object with Id say 'xyz'. and sends same Id  to submit order method.
     B. Now Buy method is waiting for reply from submit order.
     C. Submit Order method can not load order Object as it is already locked by buy method.
     D. So Submit Order method is waiting to acquire lock. Hence it is dead lock condition.

Note: Both Applications use Spring MVC, Spring Web Service and Hibernate.

Please Help me out of this situation. Thanks In advance.(I can post part of the code If required)

Comment: Did you try to build a Database transaction around a web service call?

Comment: yes. Web service call is from buy method only.

Comment: And you expect, that the same transaction can be uses on the other side of the Web Service (Order)?

Comment: Yes. All thing in Buy should be under one transaction. But it is not possible, and this situation is not allowing me to make submit order method(order service) transactional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is not possible to use the same Database Transaction on both sides of an web service invocation. -- It is at least simply impossible to transfer the connection over the web service.

So you have to live with the fact, that you have/need two Database transactions. One one each side. -- And in addition to that (that causes your Lazy Initialization Exception), if the web service - server side recive a entity, it is not attached to any session, so if you try to access a not yet loaded (layz loaded) property then get this layz loading exception.

What you need to do is, open a transaction, and attach the entity to this transaction first.

Comment: But when I create two transactions then it leads to dead lock situation. refer point 6,7 in question.

Comment: @Sagar I think you have to rethink the complete structure. I my humble option, it has a very bad smell. - For example: transaction and locks should be as short as possible, the invocation of an web service takes defently longer than an transaction or lock should take. -- Next: You should have clear responsibility which module is responsible for which objects. -- Next: It is not really a deadlock, it is simply the fact (depends on the isolation level), that the Order does not exist for an other transaction until the transaction that the Order creates is committed.

Comment: @Sagar: I strongly recommend to make it easyer. The server that create the Order have to store it. May you have to seperate the Order (Entity) and the Order Data (DTO Pattern). Then may the client create the OrderDto send it to the Order Server, and the Order Server constructs a Order Entity from the DTO and save it. - Or may the Order Server acts only on the DTO and the Buy Server creates the Order Entity after the Web Service invocation has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the TradeService creating the order? I would expect that to be the responsibility of the OrderService. That way there is no contention for the same resource as well.

And yes, both services should be transactional. You are getting LazyInitializationException because your load method is probably making 2 separate database calls to build the Order instance and the session's closed after the first database call.